# How can I access an attribute of the selected option in an OptionSelector?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I have an OptionSelector that delegates to an OptionSelectorDelegate, and has a ListModel for the model.  How should I access the "sometext" attribute of the ListElements?

```js
OptionSelector {
    id: optionSelector
    model: listModel
    delegate: delegator
}

Component {
    id: delegator
    OptionSelectorDelegate {
        text: name
    }
}

ListModel {
    id: listModel
    ListElement {name: "name"; sometext: "text"}
    ListElement {name: "name"; sometext: "more text"}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OptionSelector](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.04/Ubuntu.Components.OptionSelector/) has a [selectedIndex](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.04/Ubuntu.Components.OptionSelector/#selectedIndex-prop) field, which you can use to get the item from the model:

```
listModel.get(selectedIndex).sometext
```

If you are invoking this code outside of the scope of the optionSelector, you need to specify it:

```
listModel.get(optionSelector.selectedIndex).sometext
```

Comment: But then how do I get the value of the "sometext" attribute?

Comment: Editted to add that part

Comment: When I try your suggestion, I get the following error: "ReferenceError: selectedIndex is not defined".
I also tried "optionSelector.selectedIndex.filename", but it's undefined.

Comment: `optionSelector.selectedIndex` is a number, so it won't have a filename property.  If you are invoking this code outside of the scope of the optionSelector, you need to specify it: `listModel.get(optionSelector.selectedIndex).sometext`